# Does $\sum_i e_i \otimes e_i$ in $V\otimes V$ have a name?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, orthogonal-matrices

If $V$ is a vector space with orthogonal basis $(e_i)$,  consider the element
$\sum_i e_i \otimes e_i  \in V\otimes V$.
It can be shown that this element is independent of the choice of orthogonal basis.

Does this element have a name?

Answer (score 0):

You could call it the [Casimir element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_element). If $V$ is finite-dimensional, then under the identification $V \otimes V \cong V \otimes V^{\ast} \cong \text{End}(V)$ it corresponds to the identity

$$V \otimes V^{\ast} \ni \sum e_i \otimes e_i^{\ast} \mapsto \text{id}_V \in \text{End}(V)$$

and can also be called the [unit](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dualizable+object).

Comment: Thanks! I thought "Casimir" is only used when it's a Lie algebra. For "unit", I thought it's just a linear algebra question and wasn't expecting something out from category theory ;-)

Comment: @Hao: yes, that's why I said "you could call it" and not "it's called," it would be slightly unconventional.